# C++ Code Coverage using Python based Unit Testing

Tags: python, c++, unit-testing

I am using testgen software found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/testgen/).

So my test code is a script written in python and the code to be tested is in C++/C.

After getting the results from my script, I need to calculate the amount of code coverage that my Python test script was able to cover while testing the C++/C code.

I have heard about [coverage.py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage/3.7.1#downloads) as a potential coverage tool that can be used in Python. But it checks coverage for Python code and Python DLL modules only right?

Also, the compiler I am using after generating the C++ test code using my Python script is VS 2010

Comment: Not so sure if this helps anyway, gcov instrumentation is the tooling used for GCC actually. There might be something similar using the MVCS compiler.